# Glass' d interpretation – similar to that of Cohen's d?

Tags: effect-size

Following up on [this question on Cohen's *d* statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469203/what-is-the-intuition-behind-cohens-d), how is Glass' *d* to be interpreted? The [Wikipedia page on effect sizes shows a table for ranges of Cohen's *d*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_d) and their general interpretations (although I know, just like with ranges for Cohen's Kappa, these are generally rules of thumb and not to be held as truth). Do these ranges provided by Cohen and Sawilowsky also extend to metrics like Glass' *d*?

Comment: The association of words like 'small' or 'large' with values of Cohen's d (or Glass's d) should not be encouraged. The interpretation of any observed effect size is so dependent on context and research objectives that the words are not useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Glass' $d$ is almost identical in form to Cohen's $d$ differing only in whether to use a pooled standard deviation or the one from the control group then the same cut-off points would be appropriate although as you point out they are quite arbitrary. It would be better to compare with values typical for the particular field of science and for measures and studies with similar variances since the measures are chimeras of mean and variance.